# How to list storage classes using Kubernetes client

Tags: java, node.js, api, kubernetes

I am using below line of code to get details about a particular PVC

```
response = await `serverModule.kubeclient.api.v1.namespaces(ns).persistentvolumeclaims(pvc).get();`
```

The corresponding API for above call is [readNamespacedPersistentVolumeClaim](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#readnamespacedpersistentvolumeclaim) with below format

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/persistentvolumeclaims/{name}
```

Now, I am trying to call [readStorageClass](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/StorageV1Api.md#readstorageclass) using same convention as above

> response = await serverModule.kubeclient.apis.storage.k8s.io.v1.storageclasses(sc).get();

As you can see in the link, `GET /apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/{name}` is the format, I have used above syntax. But for some reason the code fails with error

```
Exported kubeclient, ready to process requests
TypeError: Cannot read property 'k8s' of undefined
```

What is the syntax error that I have made. I tried various combinations but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `client.apis["storage.k8s.io"].v1.storageclasses.get()` , Applicable to any api containing dots.
Hope it helps

Comment: response = await serverModule.kubeclient.apis.["storage.k8s.io"].v1.storageclasses(sc).get();
                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: There should not  be dot (.) after apis.
Correct syntext is :   response = await serverModule.kubeclient.apis["storage.k8s.io"].v1.storageclasses(sc).get();

Answer (score 2):

This issue is listing `PersistentVolumeClaim` is a part of `coreV1Api` of kubernetes and listing `StorageClass` is the part of `StorageV1beta1Api`. Following it the simplest code for listing storage class using JAVA client:

```
ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

// Configure API key authorization: BearerToken
ApiKeyAuth BearerToken = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("BearerToken");
BearerToken.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
// Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. "Token" (defaults to null)
//BearerToken.setApiKeyPrefix("Token");

StorageV1beta1Api apiInstance = new StorageV1beta1Api();
try {
    V1beta1StorageClassList result = apiInstance.listStorageClass();
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ApiException e) {
    System.err.println("Exception when calling StorageV1beta1Api#listStorageClass");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Following is the official documentation link for your reference:

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/StorageV1beta1Api.md#listStorageClass

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using `js` to make the api call. May be some syntax issue.If you notice,the working part of the code which is for PVC has this API convention "/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/persistentvolumeclaims/{name}" and my corresponding code is "serverModule.kubeclient.api.v1.namespaces(ns).persistentvolumeclaims(pvc).get();". The code which fails has API "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/{name}" for which I have written "serverModule.kubeclient.apis.storage.k8s.io.v1.storageclasses(sc).get();". Some where it is not able to take "apis.storage.k8s.v1." part

Comment: Could you please point out the github of k8s client you're using. In javascript alone I can find multiple clients and those clients have different ways to call the API

Comment: I am using "npm install @kubernetes/client-node" to install the client. I assume this is the github link "https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript"